# How to get selected text on screen in Mac OSX with Python?

Tags: python, macos, cocoa, mouseevent, hook

I'm trying to get the selected text on any app using Python in Mac OSX like below:

[image: like this picture]

As for now, I do it by sending keystrokes (Command + C) to copy the selected text on the screen (after a MouseReleased event), then retrieve the content from clipboard. The trick works for me but not as good as the way PopClip does.

Anyone knows how to do it better?

Comment: Perhaps an Automator service?